# Xcode builds app correctly, but unable to launch?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, compilation

I'm running 10.10 with Xcode 6.1.

And I'm having trouble getting an app I wrote to work. After hours and hours I finally got it to build correctly after accidentally messing with something, but now I'm getting an error I don't have permission to view the file (if I open directly in Xcode) or if I try to open it from the Finder it says the App is damaged or corrupt and can't be open. If it matters it's written in Swift.

I've literally spent 6 hours on this (Just trying to get it to build) so any help would be greatly appreciated! Austen

Here's the Xcode workspace, project, files, and a build if anyone needs to take a look: http://pattersoncode.ca/ServerChecker.zip

Answer (score 0):

There are a several issues here. I can't help you with all of them, but I can put you on the right path, at least.

The app won't launch because it wasn't built correctly. Specifically, there's not any actual binary executable in the built .app. You can see this by right-clicking on the built `Server Checker.app` and choosing `Show Package Contents`. In there is a `Contents` folder; open that. Inside that should be a folder called `MacOS`, in which your actual binary executable would be. But it's not there. This isn't really an app at all.

Reason is, you have a custom build rule for swift files that's making them not compile at all. Just remove that, you don't need it.

In Xcode, click on the top-level item of the project (it says something like ServerChecker, 1 target, OS X SDK 10.10). Then, under TARGETS, select ServerChecker. Click Build Rules. The thing that says "Swift source files using Script", that we don't need. Click the little X in the top-right corner, and click Delete when prompted. Now try to build again.

You'll get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
```

Since you don't have a main.swift file, your app doesn't have a main entry point. In Swift, you must either provide an `NSApplicationMain` function (usually in main.swift), or you can declare your app delegate as NSApplicationMain, which has the effect of calling NSApplicationMain with your delegate class. I recommend the latter.

Open up AppDelegate.swift, and add `@NSApplicationMain` to your AppDelegate class. It should look like:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
...
}
```

Now your app should build again. Right-click it and `Show Package Contents` to verify that there's actually an executable binary in there.

The app still won't run. It looks like on launch there's an error that a library couldn't be loaded.

Hopefully that helps you get moving, anyway. I really need to get back to work now. :)